# Github file history doesn't show all my commits

Tags: git, github, repository

I am trying to view the history of a file in my repo but for some reason it is only giving the single commit made by a branch that is not relevant to me.

I have tried to change the view to another branch, but I am still getting one commit from that same branch even though I should be seeing multiple commits.

For example, I have one branch called p238 and one branch called feature-123, I am only seeing the commits made from p238 and nothing before (not even from the master branch). feature-123 is ahead of everything else and will soon be merged into master.

What is happening here? Am I missing something?

Comment: Do you have pushed  feature-123 to your GitHub repo?

Comment: feature-123 has over 100 commits pushed to the repo.

Comment: Are you trying to see the commit of a specific file? Or the commits of a branch. Because if a file hasn't been modified in any commit of the feature-123 branch, you wouldn't see one commit in said branch when looking at the history of that file.

Comment: I'm trying to view the commit history of a particular file. I have made changes to the file in feature-123 but all I'm seeing is commits from p238.

Comment: It could be that you have renamed the file. Try using the 'git log --follow' function to also track across the rename.

Comment: I haven't renamed anything.